# Zend_Cache save from command line and access from browser

Tags: php, zend-framework

May be I am this is super-easy but I couldnt' figure out way. I have script running in command line which save cache using Zend_Cache

```
$frontendOptions = array(
            'lifetime' => NULL,
            'automatic_serialization' => true
        );

$backendOptions = array(
            'cache_dir' => "/home/tmp/cache"
        );

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                    'File',
                    $frontendOptions,
                    $backendOptions);
$vars = Array("id1" => "12121", "id2" => "2232");
$cache->save($vars, "p_11");
```

I can access saved cache from command line:

```
$cache->load("p_11");
```

In above both case, I have app.php file that run in command line using php-cli.

Now, I want to access p_11 cache using browser something like http://mytestserve.lan/test_cache.php

I have create object with cache factory like above. All the parameters are same as above. However when I try to load cache p_11, i do not variables set from command line. What went wrong?

Comment: it might be useful to include your `$frontendOptions` and `$backendOptions` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that when you accessed cache file for the first time via command-line it was created with you as an owner and certain access mask (maybe 0600).

But when you're trying to open the file via browser, you act as completely different user (say, www or apache). Just maybe the apache user cannot access that file.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @akond probably you should try to play with `cache_file_umask` and `cache_file_perm` options for the backend configuration:

```
$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir'        => "/home/tmp/cache",
    'cache_file_umask' => 0775, 
    'cache_file_perm'  => 0775);
```

Comment: Note that in ZF 1.12, `cache_file_umask` is deprecated (and will trigger an E_DEPRECATED error) in favor of `cache_file_perm` since it really wasn't functioning as a umask. See [ZF-12047](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12047).

Comment: Thanks b.b3rm4rd, "'cache_file_perm'  => 0775" didn't worked me. But I assume this is more related to OS.